# HTML in CDO Messaging: Images on the same row

Tags: html, css, image, email, cdo.message

I have a simple vbs that could send email with pictures. The problem is, I couldn't get the format that I want. I need the images to be aligned at the same row, I also tried using div align but still getting the same result.

Thank you so much!

---

```
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = "two attached pic"
objMessage.From = "email@yahoo.com" 
objMessage.To = "email@yahoo.com" 
objMessage.HtmlBody="<h><body><b>Before</b></h><br><br><br><img src=1.jpg style=width:304px;height:228px><br><br><br><b>After</b></h><br><br><br><img src=2.jpg style=width:304px;height:228px><br></body></html>" 
Set objBP = objMessage.AddRelatedBodyPart("C:\Users\A&P IT\Desktop\edkbr\wallpaper\1.jpg", "1.jpg", 1)
objBP.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<1.jpg>"
Set objBP = objMessage.AddRelatedBodyPart("C:\Users\A&P IT\Desktop\edkbr\wallpaper\2.jpg", "2.jpg", 1)
objBP.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<2.jpg>"
objBP.Fields.Update

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")="email@yahoo.com"
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")="password"
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.gmail.com"
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=465
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate")=1
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")=1
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

objMessage.Send
Set objMessage = Nothing
```